# Measure of set of points that are $\epsilon$ away from measure 0 set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lebesgue measure 0 set.  Define $U_\epsilon = \{z \in \mathbb{R}^n: distance(z, D) < \epsilon \}$.  Can I show that $m(U_{\epsilon}) = O(\epsilon^n)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$?  If this is not true how about $O(\epsilon^2)$ and if $D$ is bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly not true : take $D=\mathbb{Q}^n$, then $U_\epsilon =\mathbb{R}^n$ for every $\epsilon$.

I should add that the boundedness assumption doesn't help : take $D=\mathbb{Q}^n \cap [0,1]^n$ for instance.

Comment: Great examples here. My question would be, can you come up with sufficient conditions on $D$ so that the statement given in the question is in fact true?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг It's supposed to be true for a holomorphic variety, but I am not sure why.  I was hoping it had to be true for a measure 0 set because holomorphic varieties are measure 0.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a simpler condition, honestly.

Comment: Holomorphic varieties satisfy that the codimension is greater than or equal to 1.  That may be the condition to make the statement true.